Network is not working in VM migrated to Proxmox
I'm migrating a HYPER-V Ubuntu VM Proxmox VE. It starts, but it has a network problem.

Ubuntu 22.04 Hyper-V was installed and running on the virtual machine, I switched it to Proxmox 8.2.2, but my network is not working.

22.04.4 LTS  Ubuntu Hyper-v was installed and running on the virtual machine, I switched it to Proxmox 8.2.2. But my network is not working.

Solved my problem   step by step
rm /etc/netplan/*.yaml

then  shutdown ubuntu
Open proxmox VM hardware delete network adapter and then add new networkadapter
Start VM ubuntu
ifconfig 

Seen adapter name  enp6s18
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

write new yaml file insert
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp6s18:
      dhcp4: true

ctrl+o then ctrl+x save file
   sudo netplan apply

Now working my virtual machine  Dhcp.

If ifconfig is not showing another interface than the loopback, it may appear if you run "ifconfig -a" which shows all the interfaces, even the I configured ones. you have to configure the enp6s18 with the network to match proxmox.
Use netplan to configure the interface if you don't use the desktop
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/configuring-networks

As seen in the picture, my main problem is Virtio1 is disabled, how can I activate it? I think the problem will disappear when enabled.

It's not enabled because it's not configured, you can configure it and use "netplan apply" or you can use the legacy ifconfig command "ifconfig enp6s18 up" to bring the nic up. "ifconfig -a" should have listed the nic even if it's down.
